# CAPTURAR DATOS RECIBIDOS DE OTRA WEB

Tags: php

Excelente día comunidad...
Ando con un detalle:
Cierto sitio web me envía (con POST) datos (array) de resultados de encuesta...
Sin embargo no  consigo como obtenerlos,

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');   
echo $data;
```

Tengo el código de arriba pero no me funciona (soy principiante, por si alguien podría darme solo una idea, yo procedo a investigar más)

Comment: De la documentación: *`php://input` no está disponible con enctype="multipart/form-data"*. ¿Es tu caso?

Comment: lo quiero no es imprimirlo tal cual, si no solamente obtenerlo para después enviarlo a otro enlace (el problema es que no consigo recibirlo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes, contemplando los dos posibles escenarios y el detalle de porqué no puedes ver la información:

1. Abres la página en tu navegador y no puedes ver el resultado de `echo $data;` porque se trata de una petición "local" y no se ha recibido información.
2. El otro sitio envía la información y tampoco puedes ver el resultado porque es una petición independiente y no tienes acceso, la respuesta del servidor es enviada solo al otro sitio.

Lo más que puedes hacer es capturar la información, guardarla en un archivo con [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php), formateada con [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-export).

```
<?php
// Obtener información
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Formatear contenido
$export = var_export($data, true);
// Fecha y hora de la petición
$feha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Crear contenido para agregar a archivo
$contenido = "-----\nFecha: $fecha\nDatos: $export\n-----\n";

// Guardar en archivo
file_put_contents('peticiones.txt', $contenido, FILE_APPEND);
```

Cada que el otro sitio haga una petición se va a actualizar el archivo, agregando los datos enviados. Solo tienes que abrirlo para ver lo que se recibió y poder usar esa información de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

**Importante:** La carpeta donde se va a guardar el archivo debe tener permisos de escritura; en este caso, se va a guardar en la misma carpeta donde está el script.

### Actualización: Obtener datos desde POST

De acuerdo a los datos que recibes, según lo que escribiste en comentarios:

```
'textfield=%7Bclave%3A12683-MHU-1210-1919%2Cprueba%3A1%2Cpractica%3Atrue%2Caccion%3Atermina_practica%7D'
```

Si la petición es realizada por método POST, deberías acceder directamente a cada variable desde `$_POST` o, bien, para el formato que deseas, guardarlo como [JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
// Obtener datos
$data = $_POST;

// Si no deseas guardar la variable textfield, elimínala
unset($data['textfield']);

// Crear contenido JSON para agregar a archivo
$contenido = json_encode($data);

// Guardar en archivo, sobrescribiendo
file_put_contents('peticiones.txt', $contenido);
```

Comment: excelente!, sin embargo me va acumulando los datos... se puede limpiar el archivo para que los datos sean unicos cada vez que se guarden (ya que esa info. La enviare a otra pagina, por lo que ya no ocupo que se queden alli)

Comment: Y gracias nuevamente

Comment: Sí, solo quita el tercer parámetro `FILE_APPEND` de la función `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: 'textfield=%7Bclave%3A12683-MHU-1210-1919%2Cprueba%3A1%2Cpractica%3Atrue%2Caccion%3Atermina_practica%7D'                              (Esto es lo que me guarda)

Comment: lo que quiero que guarde es esto :  (Existe manera de hacerlo?)                                                                                           {"clave":"12683-MHU-1210-1919","prueba":"1","practica":true,"accion":"termina_practica"}

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, revisa la última parte.

Comment: Excelente, mil gracias por salvarme el día...todo me funcionó

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que les puede servir.